# Pass macro value at command line

Tags: c, macros, makefile

Hi i have some code and compiled using make file.Let me see you peace of code in which i got trouble.

```
#if (TEST_MACRO == 1)
printf("Use test configuration");
//some code
#else
printf("Use actual configuration");
//some code
#endif
```

And in make file have added that macro using

```
CFLAGS = -DTEST_MACRO
```

Now I compiled program using

```
make mytarget TEST_MACRO=0
```

Then also it going to execute test configuration code.

So my question is that is default value of macro in makefile is **1**?
If yes then how to make it **0**?

I tried something like

```
CFLAGS = -DTEST_MACRO=0
```

But in this case it always going to execute actual configuration even i pass value **1**.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 3):

Use `ifdef` instead - easier to use.

i.e.

```
#ifdef TEST_MACRO
....
#else
...
#endif
```

Then compile with `-DTEST_MACRO` to add. To compile without do not use `-DTEST_MACRO`

Comment: I know this is the way.. but need to give makefile to customer and he/she just compile with different value of test macro. he/she haven't any rights to modify the makefile/source.